# How to restore a back up file into pgadmin III

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgadmin-3, data-storage

My backup file containing about 50-60 tables , but I am able to just load only 6 tables for a new db and 31 tables for postgis dbase . And this was the error when I restore a backup file.

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 1393; 0 0 SHELL TYPE box2d postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  type "box2d" already exists
    Command was: CREATE TYPE box2d;
```

I should I resolve this problem. I am using PostgreSQL 9.1 and please help me how can I load all tables without any errors.my backup file contains 90 MB.

Comment: can you show us how you made the backup and how you are trying to restore it.

Comment: I think this question is a better fit for dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think this question is OK here as the error relates specifically to using PostGIS as opposed to the generalities of using Postgresql.

Comment: selecting the database and Tools-->Restore and neither of the properties are changed like only data, only schema etc.

Comment: Like @altefren said, it should be working but if you don't want errors doing a find and replace to change "CREATE X" to "CREATE OR REPLACE X" should get rid of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are a victim of the fact that spatially enabling a PostgreSQL db with PostGIS creates a bunch of functions in the "public" namespace. If you backup the public namespace and then restore it to a PostGIS db these functions will already exist, causing errors. As Paul Ramsey wrote (in a [blog post](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2010/09/postgis-back-up-restore.html) explaining the issue in detail and giving advice):

> you can ensure the greatest ease in doing dump and restore of PostGIS
>   data if you ensure that you store no data in the "public" schema.